# CDK Implement IGrantable for multiple resources

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cdk

Is it possible to create a construct that implements `IGrantable` by composing multiple `IGrantable` resources?

Let's say I have a construct:

```js
export class MyLambdas extends Construct {
  private readonly firstLambda: Function;
  private readonly secondLambda: Function;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    this.firstLambda = new Function(this, ...);
    this.secondLambda = new Function(this, ...);
  }
}
```

I'd like to implement `IGrantable` for this construct, so that both `firstLambda` and `secondLambda` are granted permissions.

I would have guessed that this would be achieved using `CompositePrincipal`, eg:

```js
export class MyLambdas extends Construct implements IGrantable {
  private readonly firstLambda: Function;
  private readonly secondLambda: Function;

  public grantPrincipal: IPrincipal;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    this.firstLambda = new Function(this, ...);
    this.secondLambda = new Function(this, ...);

    this.grantPrincipal = new CompositePrincipal(
      this.firstLambda.grantPrincipal,
      this.secondLambda.grantPrincipal);
  }
}
```

However firstly the types don't work (`CompositePrincipal` accepts `PrincipalBase` rather than `IPrincipal`), and secondly it doesn't seem to grant the permissions even with some casting.

Has anyone managed to achieve this? :)

Comment: You could try: `this.grantPrinciple = new CompositePrincipal(new ArnPrincipal(firstLambda.role.roleArn), new ArnPrincipal(secondLambda.role.roleArn)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work (at least I tested this on glue jobs with a `CompositePrincipal` for the glue job roles, and the glue jobs couldn't access the bucket that I called `grantRead` on)